# Command that will only print value once although it appears many times

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a big txt file in which values are are repeating many times. Is there some command that I can use that will go through file and if one value appears once do not repeat it again?

```
SO4
HOH
CL
BME
HOH
SO4
HOH
CL
BME
HOH
SO4
HOH
SO4
HOH
CL
BME
HOH
SO4
HOH
CL
BME
HOH
CL
```

So it should look something like this:

```
S04   
HOH  
CL   
BME
```

The thing is that I have huge number of different values, so can't do it manualy like here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the command `sort` with the option `--unique`:

```
sort -u input-file
```

If you want to write result to FILE instead of standard output, use the option `--output=FILE`:

```
sort -u input-file -o output-file
```

---

The command `uniq` also could be applied. In this case the identical lines must be consequential, so the input must be sorted preliminary - thanks to [@RonJohn](https://askubuntu.com/users/69438/ronjohn) for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992861/command-that-will-only-print-value-once-although-it-appears-many-times/992863#comment1602377_992863) note:

```
sort input-file | uniq > output-file
```

---

I like the `sort` command for similar cases, because of its simplicity, but if you work with large arrays the `awk` approach from John1024's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/992865/566421) could be more powerful. Here is a time comparison between the mentioned approaches, applied on a file (based on the above example) with almost 5 million lines:

```
$ cat input-file | wc -l
20000000

$ TIMEFORMAT=%R
$ time sort -u input-file | wc -l
64
7.495

$ time sort input-file | uniq | wc -l
64
7.703

$ time awk '!a[$0]++' input-file | wc -l      # from John1024's answer
64
1.271

$ time datamash rmdup 1 < input-file | wc -l  # from αғsнιη's answer
64
0.770
```

Other significant difference is [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992861/command-that-will-only-print-value-once-although-it-appears-many-times/992863#comment1602226_992865) mentioned by [@Ruslan](https://askubuntu.com/users/113421/ruslan):

> `sort -u` will only print the result once the input has ended, while
>   this `awk` command will do print each new result line on the fly (this
>   may be more important for piped input than file).

Here is an illustration:

[image]

In the above example, the loop (shown below) generates 500 random combinations, each with a length of three characters, of the letters A-D. These combinations are piped to `awk` or `sort`.

```
for i in {1..500}; do cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-D | head -c 3; echo; done
```

Comment: It is very simple command! Many thanks! All the best.

Comment: Oh, for the days when one utility did one thing and did it well!!  `sort input-file | uniq`!!!!

Answer (score 15):

If you want to keep the output lines in the same order as the input lines, use:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' file
SO4
HOH
CL
BME
```

How it works:

This uses associative array `a` to count the number of times each line has been previously seen.  If it has not been previously seen, the line is printed.

Comment: It is very tricky with `awk`, but `sort -u` is the easy way.

Comment: @PierreFrançois, but `sort -u` also is the slowest way :) I've updated my answer with a time comparison between the two approaches.

Comment: Also, `sort -u` will only print the result once the input has ended, while this `awk` command will do print each new result line on the fly (this may be more important for piped input than file).

Comment: Thanks for this note, @Ruslan! I've tried to illustrate it in my answer.

Comment: I must confess that the`awk` solution is a very good one, albeit not as easy to read as `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GNU** `datamash` here also as follows, and will keep the line order.

```
datamash rmdup 1 < infile
```

Comment: According to the `time` [comparison](https://askubuntu.com/a/992863/566421) this is the fastest solution, provided here.